# Symfony relantionship between 3 tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine

3 tables: products, colors and products_colors. I can't insert data in products_colors when i try to add a new product.

Relantionships are OneToMany between products and products_colors and OneToMany between colors and products_colors.

Colors are always the same and in my form available colors can be selected by checkboxes with values as color_id.

So i have to interact with products_colors table adding/removing elements....

How to?

Doctrine schema is ok and mapping too.

---

These are my formtype:

Addproduct formtype:

```
    $builder
        ->add('products', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ColorsType::class,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'prototype' => false
        ])
        ->add('add', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Add product'))
    ;
```

ColorsType:

```
    $builder
        ->add('color', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Colors::class,
            'query_builder' => function(ColorsRepository $repo) {
                return $repo->getColorsRep();
            },
            'choice_value' => function (Colors $entity = null) {
                return $entity ? $entity->getColorsId() : '';
            },
            'choice_label' => function (Colors $entity = null) {
                return $entity ? $entity->getColor() : '';
            },
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'mapped' => true
        ))
    ;
```

Comment: Please, post the mapping also and the adder/remover. I highly suspect you're doing this operation on the inversed side, so it's not perceived by doctrine.

Comment: Looks like you're naturally have just N:N relationship between `products` and `colors`. You can just update your mappings accordingly and Doctrine will handle the rest by itself

Comment: I don't know how to add and remove elements: can you posting entities functions for me? I tried very solution but i have issues everytime

Comment: as spotted by @Flying, is there any reason for using 2 OneToMany relations instead of 1 ManyToMany relation between Product and Color ?

Comment: ManyToMany should be used to add colors combined to products. Colors are always the same and already exist. I have to interact only with products_colors table to add/remove combined product_id/color_id and so i used OneToMany relationship

Comment: Did you created the datatable product_color? If yes, as mentionned in previous comment, you should not create or interact with db, and only let doctrine do the job. A ManyToMany relation should do the trick.

Comment: @BartBartoman I created product_colors db but ManyToMany should be to add colors or not? Colors do not change! They area always the same

Comment: I solved with this code:
    
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Colors")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_colors",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="color_id", referencedColumnName="color")}
     * )
     */

and it works but doctrine:schema:validate give me this error:
Column name 'id' referenced for relation from Entity\Colors towards Entity\Products does not exist.

How can i resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You try to do the job of Doctrine...

When you have two entities : **Product** and **Color**
A Product can have many colors, and a Color could be assigned to many product, so the relation is logically **ManyToMany**

When you link those entities, Doctrine will make a table `product_color` or `color_product` which refer each link between entities.

```
product
----------------
id      | name
----------------
1       | Shirt
2       | Skirt


color
----------------
id      | name
----------------
1       | Red
2       | Blue
3       | Green


product_color
------------------------
id_product | id_color
------------------------
1          | 1     # Red shirt
1          | 2     # Blue shirt
2          | 2     # Blue skirt
```

See more on the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html